Colored box paragraph that stays on text grid
Is there any straightforward way to produce this kind of output with the distance between the baseline of the last line before the box and the baseline of the first line within the box as well as the distance between the baseline of the last line within the box and the baseline of the first line after the box being exactly 3\baselineskip? (So that everything stays 100% on the text grid.)

Code that produces the current output:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\definecolor{lightgrey}{HTML}{f2f2f2}
\begin{document}
\noindent\ipsum[4]
\addvspace{1.25\baselineskip}
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
    colback=lightgrey,%
    colframe=lightgrey,%
    boxrule=0mm,%
    boxsep=.75\baselineskip,%
    arc=5mm,%
    rounded corners,%
    breakable,%
    left*=0pt,%
    right*=0pt,%
    grow to right by=1.5\baselineskip,%
    grow to left by=1.5\baselineskip,%
    ]
    \ipsum[4]
\end{tcolorbox}
\addvspace{1.25\baselineskip}
\noindent\ipsum[4]
\end{document}


Reading your response to the first answer you received doesn't, frankly, make me inclined to post another. Yes, I understand that the answer didn't provide a solution and I also get that the poster who responded was wrong about your code having errors. But there are more courteous ways of pointing such things out.

Re. the qn.: define 'straightforward' and 'this kind of output'. Clearly you don't want the same output. What you seem to want, if I take the specifications literally, is that the text before and after the box overlap it. But, regardless of that, if your text is forced to the grid, then you can add a box of this kind while keeping it on the grid. But there is no good way to keep it on the grid. Doing so requires removing all glue, which  produces typographically poorer results in most cases. If all you want is text - no headings, title, lists, maths etc. - that's different.

@cfr I appreciate that you are willing to help me even though you didn't like the way I conducted myself.
I don't remember exactly what I had written, but I do remember that I was actually frustrated, as I had the impression that the user was just trying to make himself important, to my detriment. The "answer" didn't even begin to solve any problem, it had just removed parts of the code. I absolutely did not understand why someone would post such an answer, and I think it may discourage other users from looking at the question if there is already an answer.

As if that wasn't enough, for some reason the user wanted me to believe that I had to use the lipsum package instead of the ipsum package, which I also didn't understand and reinforced the impression that it was really all about pomposity. I think I can say that I normally behave very kindly towards other people, and perhaps the user actually had good intentions and naively assumed that I was stupid and didn't have the slightest idea, and perhaps I could have reacted differently. But at that moment it was simply my impression that the way the user was behaving was not okay.

By the way, I also don't understand why people are downvoting my question here.

@cfr As for the question itself:
By "straightforward" I basically mean a solution that does not require me to read out the last line depth and the next line height on the lua end and insert a suitable glue, as this would be somewhat cumbersome and possibly not 100% robust. I know a lot about LuaTeX (i.e. the corresponding Lua programming), but comparatively little about advanced methods in classic TeX/LaTeX. So I thought maybe there is a cleaner solution than Lua programming.

My requirements for the output are: Text retains the normal textwidth, padding is configurable, rounded corners are configurable.
In principle, the output should look like the image, but with vertical spacing in which the middle paragraph remains exactly on the grid.

For what it is worth, I did not vote your question down. I cannot speak to the intent of the person who answered, but I suspect they may not have recognised ipsum as a package. It's possible they don't have it installed. I had to check whether it existed. lipsum and kantlipsum and blindtext are far more common and ipsum would be an easy typo, if you didn't check by compiling (which lots of posters don't).

@cfr Okay. I see.

I don't want the text of the first and third paragraphs to overlap with the box. I just want every space between lines of text to be exactly a multiple of \baselineskip.

If you add vertical glue of any kind at any point, text won't stay on the grid because glue stretches. That's why I said that keeping things on the grid will fail unless you are either only typesetting text (in a single size) or prevent LaTeX adding glue, which typically results in inferior output. If you are only using text, you can obtain similar output by adding the box to the background at shipout, rather than typesetting it inline. That way, it won't affect the position of text on the page. However, the spacing you specify would cause the text before and after to overlap the box.

So do you want three rather than two \baselineskips?

I do typeset these books on a grid. I know about stretching and shrinking. I created my own setup/configuration for proper grid typesetting.

How would I insert such a box at shipout?

You're using LuaTeX?

Yes. – LuaLaTeX.

Currently I'm using tcolorbox. The issue is that this package doesn't care about the baselines of the previous and following paragraphs. It just looks at the bounding boxes. That's why it's not trivial here to keep the space between the baselines consistent (a multiple of \baselineskip).

@cfr Yes, I want three \baselineskip. I basically worded it wrong in the question. What I meant was that the space between the paragraphs should be two \baselineskip. Maybe this is even what caused the misunderstanding with the user who provided the answer.

Using the Lua buildpage_filter callback, we can get the vertical position of every line, and insert a kern right before it if it isn't perfectly aligned with the grid.
\documentclass{book}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Definitions %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newattribute\gridattr
\newcommand{\gridsnappingon}{\gridattr=1}
\newcommand{\gridsnappingoff}{\gridattr=0}

\newdimen\gridtop
\newdimen\gridspacing
\newdimen\gridmaxdifference

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
    local attr = luatexbase.attributes.gridattr

    -- Ensure that any lines are aligned to the grid.
    local function snap_glue(head)
        local top = tex.dimen.gridtop
        local sep = tex.dimen.gridspacing
        local max_difference = tex.dimen.gridmaxdifference

        -- Recurse over every node to get the height of every line.
        local function recurse(n, height, parent)
            for m in node.traverse(n) do
                local self_height = 0
                if parent.id == node.id("vlist") then
                    if m.id == node.id("glue") then
                        self_height = node.effective_glue(m, parent)
                    elseif m.height then
                        self_height = m.height + m.depth
                    elseif m.id == node.id("kern") then
                        self_height = m.kern
                    end
                end

                local vshift = 0
                if m.shift and parent.id == node.id("hlist") then
                    vshift = -m.shift
                end

                height = height + self_height

                local grid = node.get_attribute(m, attr)
                if grid then
                    -- Process a to-be-snapped line.
                    if m.id == node.id("hlist") and m.subtype == 1 then
                        -- Check to see how far off the grid the line is.
                        local sub = -((-top + height - m.depth) % sep)
                        local add = sep + sub
                        local diff
                        if math.abs(add) < math.abs(sub) then
                            diff = add
                        else
                            diff = sub
                        end

                        -- If the line is too far off the grid, kern it to the
                        -- nearest grid line.
                        if math.abs(diff) > max_difference then
                            local kern = node.new("kern")
                            kern.kern = diff
                            parent.list = node.insert_before(parent.list, m, kern)

                            height = height + diff
                            self_height = self_height + diff
                        end
                    end
                end

                recurse(
                    m.list,
                    height - self_height + vshift,
                    m
                )
            end
        end

        recurse(head, 0, {})
    end

    -- Add a callback to snap the glue between lines to the grid.
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("buildpage_filter", function(info)
        local head = tex.lists.page_head
        if head then
            local packed = node.vpack(head)
            snap_glue(packed)
            packed.list = nil
            node.free(packed)
        end
    end, "snap_glue")

    -- We need to hide the last depth in every \vbox, since otherwise the grid
    -- snapping fails if the last line of a tcolorbox has non-zero depth.
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("vpack_filter", function(head)
        local last = node.slide(head)
        while last do
            if last.depth then
                last.depth = 0
                break
            end
            last = last.prev
        end
        return head
    end, "snap_glue")
\end{luacode*}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \gridsnappingon % Enable grid snapping.
    \gridtop=\topskip % How far the first line is from the top of the page.
    \gridspacing=\baselineskip % The distance between grid lines.
    \gridmaxdifference=0.1pt % The maximum distance a line can be from the grid.
}

\raggedbottom

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Demonstration %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Draw the grid lines.
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{%
    \multiput%
        (0in, \dimexpr -1in - \topskip - \topmargin - \headheight - \headsep)
        (0in, -\baselineskip)%
        {\numexpr \number\textheight / \number\baselineskip}%
        {\color{gridcolor}\line(1,0){\paperwidth}}%
}

\usepackage{ipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgrey}{HTML}{f2f2f2}
\colorlet{gridcolor}{red!75!black!25}

\begin{document}
    \noindent \ipsum[4]

    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        colback=lightgrey,
        colframe=lightgrey,
        boxrule=0mm,
        boxsep=.75\baselineskip,
        arc=5mm,
        rounded corners,
        breakable,
        left*=0pt,
        right*=0pt,
        grow to right by=1.5\baselineskip,
        grow to left by=1.5\baselineskip,
        before skip=\baselineskip,
        after skip=\baselineskip,
    ]
        \ipsum[4]
    \end{tcolorbox}

    \noindent \ipsum[4]

    \vskip 4pt\relax

    This is a test line.

    \begin{align}
        a &= b \\
        c &= d
    \end{align}

    And another test line.

    \vskip 4pt\relax

    \begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
        \hline
        Row & 1 \\ \hline
        Row & 2 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \vskip 7.33pt\relax

    \ipsum[4-5]
\end{document}


The advantage to this solution is that it works in a single pass, and it should work with text lines in any environment; the disadvantage is that it adds any needed space immediately before the text lines, which can sometimes be ugly. To minimize any ugly spacing, you should try and very roughly align your text to the grid using standard LaTeX vertical spacing commands, then the Lua code will take care of the fine details.

I wanted to see how this did with the example I was using for the breakable case, so I pasted the stuff I'd added above the maths you added, but I didn't remove the rest of yours. The text goes off the grid right after the tabular and continues like that until it is righted on the next page. (I'm assuming the baselines are drawn accurately.) The same thing happens, but not quite as clearly if I just use ipsum[4-5] rather than \ipsum[4] at the end. Do you know why it would do that? Is it some effect of the paragraph breaking?

@cfr Probably a bug somewhere in how I'm calculating the height/position of the lines, or maybe some weird \prevdepth thing. I can try taking a look at it if you show me the file that you used.

I can give you the longer one if you want, but if on the line right before \end{document} in your code, you change \ipsum[4] to \ipsum[4-5] you can see it fails to tweak the last lines on that page. At least, I think so.

I guess the OP hasn't told you that the boxes are supposed to adjust if there are descenders in the last line on a page ;). As far as I know, tcolorbox doesn't do that anyway. At any rate, I have no idea how to make my substitute greybox do it. They break fine. But, as you point out, they also require two runs. (But they do work with other engines, which is some advantage, I guess.) Sorry. I'll leave you alone :).

@cfr No problem at all, and thanks for catching that bug. The fix is (luckily) pretty simple: just add \raggedbottom.
